# Instantiate class extending ArrayList

Tags: java

Is it possible to create an instance of a class extending of an ArrayList?

In the example below, how can I create an instance of class Cars containing all cars data?  Is it possible this way, or do I have to remove inheritance and add a field in Cars class like --> private List Car listCars?

```
public class Cars extends ArrayList<Car>{
   public Cars() {}
}

public class Car {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're simply looking for `List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();`, then call the `add` method to accumlate elements. see the List API.

Comment: What additional functionality is your class adding to the parent class?  This is wrong.  You don't want to extend ArrayList - you want a List<Car>

Answer (score 3):

You can extend `ArrayList` as it's not a final class and has visible constructors to call. In practice however one [should favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) so below would be preferable:

```
public class Cars {
  private final List<Car> values = new ArrayList<>();

  public void add(Car c) {
    values.add(c);
  }
}
```